# Where transaction is not closed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I want to add claims to each user, depending on his role and have the following code:

```
    public async Task SetClaims()
    {
        var users = UserManager.Users;
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var roleList = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
            foreach (var role in roleList)
            {
                //await Utils.AddUserToRoleAsync(user.Id, role, UserManager);
                var userId = user.Id;
                var claims = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(userId);
                foreach (var claim in claims)
                {
                    await UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(userId, claim);
                }
                switch (role)
                {
                    case "Superadmin":
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.create"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.delete"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.edit"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.viewList"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.viewDetail"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.create.selectCompany"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.create.selectRole.fullList"));
                        break;

                    case "CompanyAdmin":
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.create"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.delete"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.edit"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.viewList"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.viewDetail"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.create.selectRole.rolesInsideCompany"));
                        break;

                    case "CompanyManager":
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.create"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.delete"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.edit"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.viewList"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.viewDetail"));
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.create.selectRole.rolesInsideCompany"));
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get an error on line:

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Permission", "users.create"));
```

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running
>   in the session.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction
>   is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

as I understand, a transaction is not closed. Where and how to do it correctly?

Comment: Just a simple guess, can you try appending .ToList() when getting your roles and claims to make sure that connection is disposed.

Comment: @user3499361, thank you, you are right!